# Z-index of child not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

Maybe it's just been a long day but I can't figure out where I'm messing up this. Essentially the black box should be hidden behind the parent and then slid out (the intended idea is that when an input is changed it would slide out a save button for the user to click on). For sake of not worrying about whats triggering it, I have just put a button that does the slideout action. However how is the .configSave box not hidden behind the parent with correct z-index settings.

Here is the jsfiddle to view:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBuyG/2/

Thanks.

-Seth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `z-index` is always relative to the closest explictly positioned element; each such element creates its own layer.

If you want to hide the `#configSave` behind its parent `#configBox`, you will need to assign it a `z-index` of `-1`. The `z-index` of the `#boxostuff` or `#configBox` does not matter then. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qBuyG/15/))

If you want to hide the `#configSave` behind the (currently transparent) `#boxostuff`, you will need to assign it a `z-index` lower than that - again, the `z-index`of `#configBox` does not matter. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qBuyG/17/), [with background](http://jsfiddle.net/qBuyG/19/))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That definitely gave me the answer, with some deeper understanding of the issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/qBuyG/13/

I set the z-index of the element you want hidden to -1 and removed the other z-index.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way of getting it to work as you've got it. Can you take the link out of the box? It works if it's not inside the box it needs to be behind.